# Hello i have new problem with uinty Andriod ANR crash

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, android-anr-dialog

I have ANR errors and I do not know where that come from, can anybody help me find out?

Error is :

> Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the
> touched window has not finished processing certain input events that
> were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 44. Wait
> queue head age: 5519.0ms.)